Не могу подключиться к github для управления репозиториями
Добавил ключи ssh к github, он отображается в github как SHA256:s/xdKKwvNqQLx0UEzQhYLZKqwYWvRaygc/**********, но когда в git Bash ввожу команду " ssh -T git@github.com" мне выводит другой ключ

The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.4)' can't be
established. ED25519 key fingerprint is
SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/**************

Уже и config добавлял:
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personal_key
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Название ключа верное.
И много других способов пробовал, но не могу победить.

Это не ваш ключ, а ключ сервера. И вам нужно решить, доверяете ли вы этому серверу с этим ключом

Ключи сервера можно сверить по официальной документации
